# How to skip validation for the field not exists in form using Formik + Yup?

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

I am working on formik+Yup in react-native. 
I want to add validation if a particular field exists in the form, otherwise, there should not be any validation or skip validation for that field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How can you detect whether the field in question "exists in the form"? I had a situation where I hid fields using a dropdown that was also inside the form, i.e. there was a form value for that dropdown. → I was able to use yup's `mixed.when`. I also had a situation where different validation should be applied based on the form's props. → I was able to do that using withFormik's ability to accept a function `((props: Props) => Schema)` for `validationSchema`.